# Realmobject loses reference in activity A after changing realm database in activity B

Tags: android, realm

I have 2 activities, Activity A and B.
Activity A has a Company(Realm Object). From activity A I go in activity B. In activity B you can add Product(Realm Object) which keeps a reference to the Company selected in activity A. The problem is that after adding a Product the reference of Company in activity A becomes null and I can't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure Realm instance in Activity A is not closed when user opens Activity B ?

Comment: Put up some code..

Comment: I checked it in onPause and it's not closed. I can't post code because it's very big. The  idea is simple from my point of view. Now i am thinking there might be ANR errors. I tried to use execute the product insert in async mode but it didn't work. The problem is hapenning only when I change the databse in activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are taking company reference object from Activity A when you can use realm to get selected company using company id (I am assuming that each company has primary key company Id) in activity B only.

Just pass company unique key to Activity B from Activity A using `intent`. search that company from realm using that unique key

```
Company company = realm.where(Company.class).equalTo("your company unique key column name",uniqueKeyPassFromActivityAForSelectedCompany).findFirst();
```

use this company object taken from realm database to reference it to your product object. Hope this will help

*Note : I am depending on my memory for finding realm object from its unique key . So above syntax may have typos.*